# Keras Shape with unknown rank

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am using the code from [here](http://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) in order to test out LSTM networks on text generation. The only line that I changed is

```
raw_text = open('books/(1) The Hunger Games.txt').read()
```

instead of

```
filename = "wonderland.txt"
raw_text = open(filename).read()
```

And I get this error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Total Characters: 521930
Total Vocab: 50
Total Patterns: 521830
100 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
    model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 294, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 398, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 569, in __call__
    self.add_inbound_node(inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 632, in add_inbound_node
    Node.create_node(self, inbound_layers, node_indices, tensor_indices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 164, in create_node
    output_tensors = to_list(outbound_layer.call(input_tensors[0], mask=input_masks[0]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py", line 227, in call
    input_length=input_shape[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1836, in rnn
    axes = [1, 0] + list(range(2, len(outputs.get_shape())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 462, in __len__
    raise ValueError("Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.")
ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.
```

I've been looking around, I cannot understand why it just won't take the input dimensions. Any idea is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Later Edit: It doesn't work even with the original file.

Comment: Are there any differences in the format of `raw_text`?

Comment: @chris_anderson well, there shouldn't be any, both are UTF-8, the only difference is the length of the text.

Comment: I mean, maybe one is wrapped in a list and one isn't, or the data type isn't what you expected for some reason. Might be worth inspecting. There must be *something* different.

Comment: @chris_anderson I understand what you mean, but looking at the pure document it seems to be written the same way, that's why I'm perplexed ;s

Comment: @chris_anderson so, I went and downloaded the file from there (I hadn't used it, just looked over it) and it still throws the same error. This is just plain weird o.o

Comment: @Manu Andrei, if the only difference is the length of the text, could you try make the wonderland text the same length of the other one (by cutting or copying/pasting itself) to see if it is working?

Comment: @YaoZhang well, I just tried with the original file and I get the same error. It's rather weird.